# ggplot2: Impossible to create stacked bar chart WITHOUT reshape/melt?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am a novice at R and experimenting with as an alternative for data visualisation.

I am having trouble creating a stacked bar chart.

I have tried the reshape2 package with the melt function and have successfully produced one, but I had to explicitly create a dataset containing JUST the x-axis and variables that I want stacked.

It seems extremely counter-intuitive to me that we can't visualise data from a left to right sense (x-axis constant, y variables summed and overlapping).

Is there an alternate method, where I could simply perform a ggplot with the logic of:

```
ggplot(data=dataset, aes(x=Time, y1=var1, y2=var2, y3=var3.....)) +
 geom_bar(stat="identity",position="stack")
```

where y1, y2, y3 are the variables I want stacked, but do not have corresponding flags for me to use a "fill=flag" type?

I basically want to work off one large master dataset and export multiple analysis without having to excessively isolate each dataset and melt it

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data frame and the code you used to successfully create your stacked plot?

Answer (score 2):

In general a stacked bar chart is used to distinguish between variations within a single category of data. For example if you had a bar chart showing the population of three species of migratory fowl that inhabit one specific marsh.

The bars might be mallard ducks, muted swans & Canada geese. Each would have a single whole bar.

The stacking would come in when you looked at these with a trait or quality they might share which you were comparing, such as the number who migrate and those who overwinter locally. The population of each type of fowl would be split into two stacks in the bar, those migrating who are Canada geese, those not...and so on.

It is not really meant to bring together disparate traits into a stack.

So, if you have data that separates out categories of the same population, reshaping the data to create a set of individual types within your data in columns, then differentiating by factors in another (also all in the same column) that is the right move.

If you need to keep it extracted for some reason, you can probably use y = (x$1 +x$2 x$b) to create your stacks, but depending on the data that might fail miserably. The best thing to do is reshape so that the quality you are counting is in a column and you compare those members across some other column with stacks.

If you need to use the data in another format later, create a temporary table, plot and then `remove()` it and `gc()` after graphing to get your memory back